# Retrieve a list of Ids from a table where all the records have a given status

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table with data related to books.

Schema:

```
BookKey PRIMARY KEY,
BookID,
Status
```

The primary key of the table is a `BookKey` and each `BookKey` belongs to one `BookId`.

Each row also has a status field. Possible status codes are `A`, `L`, `S`.

I want to build a query to list all `BookID` for which all `BookKey` have a `Status = S`.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. Can you add table definitions, sample data and expected output to your question by clicking the [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/225343/edit). Add the table definitions as create table statements and the data as text please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT BookId
FROM datatable
GROUP BY BookID 
HAVING 0 = SUM(BookKey NOT IN ('S'))
```